# indexing files in folder

Tags: solr, lucene, indexing, sphinx

How can I index all doc files in particular folder?
Let's say I have `mydocuments` folder which contains `doc` and `docx` files. I need to index all files in that folder for efficient search. What can you suggest for indexing folder for `doc` files?
Note: I have looked for sphinx but it seems it indexes only xml and mssql.

Comment: Which version of solr are you using? Did you take a look at https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler or SolrCell? With them you can index doc-files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer applies to Lucene.

Lucene doesn't "**directly**" provide an API to index a file or a folder's contents. What we have to do is to

- Parse a file. You may use [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) which supports parsing a huge variety of files.
- Populate [Lucene Document](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Document.html) object with that information.
- Pass that document to the IndexWriter.addDocument()
- Repeat above steps for each file, i.e. each different entry in the Index.

The problem with direct indexing, even if it exists, is loss of flexibility in field creation and selection of content that goes with that field in a particular document.

The following is an excellent tutorial where you can find the sample code: [Lucene in 5 minutes](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html)

Answer (score 1):

I assume your problem is indexing a list of text files that are in a certain folder. So, this is a sample code to index them. However, if you are indexing word documents, then you need to change the getDocument method to parse and populate the Lucene document.

The key points are:

1. Create an IndexWriter.
2. Get the list of files in a folder using dir.listFiles() method.
3. Iterate through the files and create their Lucene documents one at a
   time
4. Add the Lucene document to index.
5. Once you finished adding documents, then commit the changes and close the indexWriter.

If you are looking for parsing and reading from word documents or PDF files, then you need to use Apache [POI](http://poi.apache.org/%20POI) and [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/%20PDFBox) libraries.

Please note I use the RAMDirectory class only for demo, you need to use FSDirectory instead.

I hope that solves your problem.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.RAMDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;


public class IndexFolders {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        String path = args[0];
        File dir = new File(path);

        Directory indexDir = new RAMDirectory();
        Version version = Version.LUCENE_40;
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(version);
        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(version, analyzer);
        IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(indexDir, config);

        for (File file : dir.listFiles()){
            indexWriter.addDocument(getDocument(file));
        }

        indexWriter.commit();
        indexWriter.close();
    }


    public static Document getDocument(File file) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        while(input.hasNext()){
            builder.append(input.nextLine());
        }

        Document document = new Document();
        document.add(new Field("text", builder.toString(),org.apache.lucene.document.TextField.TYPE_STORED));
        return document;
    }


}
```

Comment: Instead of just posting code, try to include at least a sentence of explanation.  SO is meant to be a reference not just to the OP but to others coming here with the same problem.  Without an explanation it helps a lot fewer people.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jason thanks for the comment. I have done that.